# Cordova: How can I find all <a> tags in inappBrowser

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, anchor, javascript-injection

I have created c cordova app that uses InappBrowser. In loadStop method of inappbrowser I want to fetch all the `<a>` tags used in that page. I have used:

```
 function onInAppBrowserStop(event) {
        var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
        alert("Anchors" + doc);
}
```

but it doesn't give me any anchor tags. Then I want to do JavaScript injection. If the `<a>` links are from specific domain I wanted to open it in External browser (_system).

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If I get this right, you can not open a new Window and modify its content with JavaScript. 
There is only a callback for errors, to show a message and the possibility to insert CSS.

`inAppBrowserRef.insertCSS({ code: "body{font-size: 25px;" });`

and

`inAppBrowserRef.executeScript({ code: scriptErrorMesssage }, executeScriptCallBack);`

BTW:

```
function onInAppBrowserStop(event) {
    var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    alert("Anchors" + anchors.length); // what was the "doc" variable?
}
```

Comment: doc is my document variable

Comment: @Purva Stefan is trying to say that the function in the question doesn't alert any info about the anchors. Also it doesn't _return_ any info about the anchors.